# Fill remaining length of array with falsy values using Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an array of arrays that looks like this:

```
const difficulties = [
  [true, true],
  [true],
  [true, true, true],
  [true]
]
```

What I’d like to do is to perform a transform on the array using Ramda, so that each of the sub-arrays is filled up with `false`, looking like this:

```
[
  [true, true, false],
  [true, false, false],
  [true, true, true],
  [true, false, false]
]
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Ramda you could use `R.times` and `R.propOr`:

```js
const difficulties = [
  [true, true],
  [true],
  [true, true, true],
  [true]
];

let difficultiesFilled = R.map(e => R.times(i => R.propOr(false, i, e), 3), difficulties);
console.log(difficultiesFilled);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

If the max length of the arrays is unknown you could do:

```
let maxLength = R.reduce(R.maxBy(R.length), [], difficulties);
```

And use that instead of `3`.

Answer (score 2):

With plain js you can find maximum length of array and use `fill()` to populate inner arrays.

```js
const arr = [
  [true, true],
  [true],
  [true, true, true],
  [true]
]

var max = Math.max(...arr.map(e => e.length))
var result = arr.map(e => e.concat(Array(max - e.length).fill(false)))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give all arrays a `.length` of `3` and `.fill()` the extra slots.

```
for (const a of difficulties) {
  const orig = a.length;
  a.length = 3;
  a.fill(false, orig);
}
```

There are many different ways to accomplish this. The above is just one. It would be a good exercise to try some other approaches on your own for practice, since this is a pretty easy task.